# Is there precedent for damage aura-type effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, aura

I'm on a homebrewing streak again, and part of the class features in question call for constant fire damage applied to creatures in range of the character in question.

Are there any monsters or spells with a similar effect (damage every turn to creatures in range) that I could base it off to preserve similar wording/mechanics?

Answer (score 5):

Various ones. Here's two examples; the first one on a monster, the second one on a spell players could cast. They work a bit differently from one another, though.

## [Balor](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Balor#content)

> Fire Aura: At the start of each of the balor's turns, each creature within 5 feet of it takes 10 (3d6) fire damage, and flammable Objects in the aura that aren't being worn or carried ignite. A creature that touches the balor or hits it with a melee Attack while within 5 feet of it takes 10 (3d6) fire damage.

## [Investiture of Flame](http://dnd5e.wikia.com/wiki/Investiture_of_Flame)

> Any creature that moves within 5 feet of you for the first time on a turn or ends it there takes 1d10 fire damage.

Comment: I wonder if the very different timing of the mechanics is because the authors wanted NPCs and PCs to work differently, basically. Also curiously, a creature can not ever take damage from Investiture even if you approach it.

Comment: I can only speculate, but the Balor one seems easier to handle (you only need to remember when the turn starts) while the player one is more complex, but also harder to avoid (you can't skirmish in and out like with the Balor) so you might be on to something.

Comment: I would guess the monster's ability is simpler (all aura damage applied at once) because the DM already has enough to keep track of.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most relevant precedent for your homebrew is the Barbarian Path of the Storm Herald. One of the options of this path applies constant fire damage to creatures in range, though notably it consumes a bonus action every turn to do so.

> Starting at 3rd level, you emanate a stormy, magical aura while you rage. The aura extends 10 feet from you in every direction, but not through total cover.
>
> Your aura has an effect that activates when you enter your rage, and you can activate the effect again on each of your turns as a bonus action. [...]
>
> [Desert Aura:] When this effect is activated, all other creatures in your aura take 2 fire damage each. The damage increases when you reach certain levels in this class, increasing to 3 at 5th level, 4 at 10th level, 5 at 15th level, and 6 at 20th level.

Answer (score 4):

The Scourge Aasimar, a playable race from Volo's Guide to Monsters (p. 105), has the AoE damaging aura Radiant Consumption as a racial ability unlocked at 3rd level. Activating it is an action.

> Your transformation lasts for 1 minute or until you end
>   it as a bonus action.
>
> [...] **at the end of each of your turns, you and each creature
>   within 10 feet of you take radiant damage equal to
>   half your level (rounded up).** In addition, once on each
>   of your turns, you can deal extra radiant damage to one
>   target when you deal damage to it with an attack or a
>   spell. The extra radiant damage equals your level.
>
> Once you use this trait, you can't use it again until you
>   finish a long rest.

The self-damage is probably not desired for your homebrew class if you want a continuous passive effect, or a weak effect, but it may be good if the aura is temporary and sufficiently powerful. Pair self-damage with resistance to the damage type in question (as the Aasimar does) to mitigate the cost of self-damage.

Comment: Interesting. Very self-contained (no damage whatsoever for moving into the aura) but also pretty clear wording!